# API Gateway Limitation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have some APIs which should be called just in working days/Hours.
Is it possible to set a working day limitation for API users in WSO2 API-Manager?

Comment: Try writing a custom rate-limiting policy using Siddhi. Refer to this for more information-> https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/advanced-topics/custom-throttling/

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom mediation policy (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/overview/) or a custom handler (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-a-custom-handler) to restrict the API based on some pre-defined logic.

Comment: There is no any particulate mediation policy about Day or time limitation. Just I can see the limitation based on Bandwidth and Count. I need to limit some of my APIs to work in Working days and working time

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [custom mediator](https://wso2.com/library/2936/) which accepts the time as params.
This mediator should check the system time and compare it with the parameter passed with the mediator. If it is not within the time specified, it should block the request and if it, allow it.

Then use the [mediation policies](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/overview/) to pass the time parameter to the gateway runtime applying the policy to the resource that you want to limit.